# Contra-rotating propellers torques

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Please look at the following mechanism for contra-rotating propellers: [YouTube video](http://youtu.be/W8jn3NuHtlU?t=43s)

When a CCW torque acts on the upper gear and a same torque acts on the lower gear (both seen from above), the torques act against each other.

But: does the whole system then move CCW or does it stand still (because the torques both cancel each other out)?

Comment: You know the blade aerodynamics are going to different between the top and and bottom blade so there is going to be an overall yaw trend related to the applied motor torque and lift produced.

Answer (score 1):

The key to your question is "will there be vorticity (net angular momentum about the axis of rotation of the engine) in the air being ejected out of the back of the engine". If the answer is "yes", then there must be a corresponding torque on the engine.